# Do I have to retype information every time I make a mistake in SQLPlus

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

If I make a mistake in SQLPlus while inputting an 'insert into' command, is there a way I can bring this information back up in order to edit it?

Comment: You need type In command line:
Rollback;

Comment: @user16063 --- and what will that do? Can you elaborate at all?

Comment: @user16063 I'm pretty sure this is a misunderstanding, Bambi wants to edit the previous command text not roll back a transaction.

Comment: Also check out `sqlcl` (it is however Java app, but very fancy prompt and Terminal Support for a CLI)

Answer (score 15):

Several ways.

You can set the `EDITOR` environment variable before running SQL*Plus (Assuming Unix), to allow use of an external text editor (`vi`, by way of example):

```
export EDITOR=vi
```

Then type `ed` in SQL*Plus to edit the previous query in the `vi` editor. Of course, you may prefer `nano`, `pico`, `emacs`, `vim` etc etc.

If you don't wish to set an environment variable, you can add `define _editor=vi` to your `$ORACLE_HOME/sqlplus/admin/glogin.sql` file instead.

My favourite way of achieving SQL*Plus edit heaven (in Unix) is by using `rlwrap`. This adds `readline` support to SQL*Plus and allows you to easily edit within SQL*Plus itself.

Install `rlwrap` from your distributions package repository (or download & compile from the website [here](http://utopia.knoware.nl/~hlub/rlwrap/#rlwrap)), then add the following to your shells startup script (`.bashrc`/`.bash_profile` or similar):

```
alias sqlplus="rlwrap -i sqlplus"
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless something has changed, just type "edit" and press enter and it'll open in Notepad (assuming Windows here) and you can change the query in there.

Answer (score -2):

For all commandline application *emacs* can be used as an interface. You can open the [shell mode](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Shell.html#Shell) and run the command line tool. Emacs will send the command you input to the command line tool and read and the display the output. Because you type your input to emacs you can manipulate your input using the emacs commands. Using this mode emacs can be used with the following oracle tools like*

- rman
- lsnrctl
- adrci
- dgmgrl

There is a special *sql-oracle* mode that especially supports *sqlplus*. I worked with it long time ago. Today I did not find it in the documentation. I searched the web and but I found only the following [link](http://sodonnell.wordpress.com/2007/07/10/emacs-and-oracle/). Maybe you can find more when searching the emacs documents. There are other  [sql modes for emacs](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/SqlMode). This page contains a reference to the [link](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SqlPlus) found by @Jack Douglas too.

A lot of people don't like emacs because they think that it is a complex tool.

Comment: I wonder if the downvotes are from `vi` fans ;) I found [this](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SqlPlus) (apparently "inspired by sqlplus-mode.el") on Google—is it the kind of thing you were talking about?

Comment: I think that this is something similar to the *sql-oracle* mode.